# Spring Integration DSL, poll from message channel

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have an service that sends data to an message channel. I'm wondering how can I specify integration flow to poll from that message channel every X seconds and read all the data that hasn't been read so far. I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
IntegrationFlows.from("inputChannel")
    //.poll(Poller.fixedDelay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
    .handle(myGenericHandlerImpl)
    .get()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

figured this one out
I was looking for this:

```
IntegrationFlows.from("inputChannel")
    .handle(myGenericHandlerImpl, e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
    .get()
```